# What is the name of alphabetical list view in contacts and how to create it?

Tags: android

In Android mobiles contact list, there is a list at the left or right side of mobile (in contact) that has all alphabet inside it, and when you put your finger on it, it will show that alphabet in a tool-tip and when click on it Android will select all contacts that their name start with that letter

What is that list name?

How to create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with RecyclerViewFastScroller

https://github.com/danoz73/RecyclerViewFastScroller

[image]